# How to push a blank name and a name on to this array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of names. I want the first option to be blank, and the last option to be "Joe".

Here is the code:

```
  def index
    @case_managers = client.personnel_search_by_client(current_client.client_id, nil, groupMnemonic: 'reimbursement_whitelist')
    @case_managers_drop_down = {}
    @case_managers.each do |case_manager|
      @case_managers_drop_down[case_manager.name] = case_manager.to_json
    end

  end
```

In my views I have:

```
= form_tag work_lists_path, :method=> 'put' do |f|
  .fieldset.field-group.field-group-inline.pull-left
    .field.field-text.field-required
      %label= t('workflow.duplicate_claim_manager')
      = select_tag('case[case_manager]', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, @selected_case_manager))
```

This correctly gets all the names. I thought before the array I would do something like `@case_managers_drop_down.push(" ")` to get a blank option and then likewise for Joe. But this doesnt seem to be working. Any idea on how I can append to this array?

Comment: Can you share you view code as you can add `include_blank` option to add blank option in drop down in view ?

Comment: added @MuhammadYawarAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a blank option at first place in `select_tag` use `include_blank` boolean attribute like :

```
= select_tag('case[case_manager]', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, @selected_case_manager), :include_blank => true)
```

OR use `prompt` like :

```
= select_tag('case[case_manager]', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, @selected_case_manager), :prompt => "Please select")
```

For last option as `joe` do it like :

```
def index
    @case_managers = client.personnel_search_by_client(current_client.client_id, nil, groupMnemonic: 'reimbursement_whitelist')
    @case_managers_drop_down = {}
    @case_managers.each do |case_manager|
      @case_managers_drop_down[case_manager.name] = case_manager.to_json
    end
    @case_managers_drop_down["joe"] = ""
end
```

Hopefully it will work!